# mercurial clone branches before merge changeset

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to clone a part of a mercurial repo (i.e. clone -r xxx), but keep all changesets prior to the specified revision i.e. not just the ancestors?

For example, given a repo that looks like this:

```
        -- 2 (branch default) -- 5 --  8 (merge) -- 9 (merge) -- 
      /                               /            /
0 -- 1  -- 3 (branch foo) ------ 6 --             /
      \                                          /
       -- 4 (branch bar) ------ 7 -------------
```

I would like to clone only the commits prior to the merge, i.e. so the resulting repo looks something like this:

```
        -- 2 (branch default) -- 5
      /
0 -- 1  -- 3 (branch foo) ------ 6
      \
       -- 4 (branch bar) ------ 7
```

but running

```
hg clone -r 7 repo repo2
```

will only give me commits 1, 4, and 7 (branch bar). It appears the only way to get what I'm after is something like this:

```
hg clone -r 5 repo repo2
cd repo2
hg pull -r 6
hg pull -r 7
```

Is that correct, or does someone know of a quicker way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered something like `hg clone repo repo2 && hg -R repo2 strip --rev 9`?  Depending on the size and complexity of the repo, this may be the quickest approach.

Comment: Certainly works for the simple case above, and probably would have done the trick for the repo I was trying to fix, so thanks.

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **have to read** `hg help clone` and remember options, which can be used more than once in one clone (-r and -b namely).

You want, in plain words "clone all in default *to 5 inclusive* **and** *FOO branch* **and** *BAR branch*"

Translate it into clone
`hg clone -r 5 -b foo -b bar <SRC REPO> <DST-REPO>`

Answer (score 1):

`hg help clone` says

```
-r --rev REV [+]       include the specified changeset
```

This is different than `hg help log`, for example, which says

```
-r --rev REV [+]         show the specified revision or range
```

The best you'll be able to do is use `-r` more than once:

```
hg clone -r 5 -r 6 -r 7 repo repo2
```

You can use `log` and revision sets to determine which other revisions you need to include.

Comment: I have been unable to get `clone` to operate on revsets. For me `hg clone -r :7 repo repo2` returns "unknown revision ':7'". Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I could have sworn that worked, but I'm afraid I didn't read the help closely enough.
`hg help clone` says "include the specified *changeset*"
`hg help log` says "include the specified *revision or range*"

Comment: Crap. Having clone use revsets certainly seems like the kind of elegant solution I was after. Oh well - it was worth checking out how versatile the revset syntax is, so thanks.